# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS RAID 1

Tags: raid, lts

I have one question about RAID in Ubuntu. When i configure RAID array in my bios is there any additional things in Ubuntu that i need to do ?
Please can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using hardware RAID. *If yor RAID controller is supported by the kernel*, your RAID system should be recognized as harddisk device since your RAID controller organizes the harddisk access and hides the physical harddisks. Ubuntu comes with all required tools to utilize the RAID system. Have a look at the [RAID setup](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup) .

Before installing the system, I would examine the I/O performance. At least with HP controllers (e.g. SmartArray B120), there are reports that the throughput is not worth the trouble with installing the proper drivers.

Comment: How to check is the hardware RAID is supported and recognized by the system properly ?

Comment: @Milen: Check the [Linux Hardware Compatibility Lists](http://www.linux-drivers.org/).